# is putting images in drawable folder enough or should i copy them to sd storage?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

In my app, i use about 150 images(500x500) for showing fruits. It is now under drawable-xxhdpi folder and it runs with no problem. Should i copy these images into internal/external storage at first run or should they be OK inside drawable only? In a real application which is in play store, which one is better in performance and design perspective?

Comment: `it runs with no problem` It seems you already answered your question.

Comment: yes but i wondered if that is a good design or not.

Answer (score 1):

> It is now under drawable-xxhdpi folder and it runs with no problem

They may not look very good on lower-density devices.

> Should i copy these images into internal/external storage at first run

No.

> should they be OK inside drawable only?

Yes.

> In a real application which is in play store, which one is better in performance and design perspective?

Leaving them as resources.